# What brands of USB Microphones are compatible with Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: usb, microphone, compatibility, ubuntu-studio, podcast

I am interested in starting a podcast (eventually going to VLog/Vodcast). I have been doing the due diligence of getting a list of the necessary elements to successfully produce a good quality podcast.

I plan to use Ubuntu Studio as my OS. And I have acquired and researched many good recommendations from some "pros" as to hardware, and of course they shell out the $$ for & use Apple or Windows products ie OS & software.

I am interested in Blue Design Yeti or Yeti X (Logitech owned) and Razer? Are there USB microphones or other production hardware ie audio interfaces out there that are compatible with and function well with Linux specifically Ubuntu Studio? (also web/vidcams)

I know this is possible due to reading several articles of bands/musicians exclusively using Ubuntu Studio to create, produce, and distribute their product ie music, videos, & podcasts or audio. In these articles they talk about the software but not so much as the hardware or peripherals ie mics, audio interfaces etc. And not just any mags but major mags being Forbes, Fast Co, Wired (yes I just typed Wired, I know) :)

I believe in and love FOSS and Linux and want to keep to and be true to this ideal! Any suggestions, recommendations, and knowledge is very much appreciated. 1Love!

Comment: Do not buy a Shure MV7 and expect it to work in Ubuntu.
I wasted over $500 on this thing, and I'm finally going to trash it and get a real microphone.

Answer (score 5):

If by "compatible" you mean is recognized by the system and can be used/recorded in an appropriate software, I'm inclined to say any USB device will do the job.

However, you will probably not get a setup or configuration software for Linux from most of the manufacturers, so you may be limited to what the "generic" mixers and tools in Ubuntu/Ubuntu Studio offer, and may not be able to access some "advanced" features some products offer.

And of course it's always wise to buy a product with a Right to Return in case you can't get it to work at all.

If you're looking for devices that people have good experience with, or that have particular Linux support, have you considered researching e.g. on [LinuxMusicians](https://linuxmusicians.com)?

Answer (score 3):

based on Audacity wiki, you have good change if you choose a Samson microphone and even better if you look for these model: C03U, UB1, C01U and Q1U
ref: https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/USB_mic_on_Linux#Samson_C01U_and_Q1U_USB_microphones